# Passing a constructor to Array.map?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, constructor, prototype-programming

How can i do something like this:

```js
var a = [1,2,3,4];
a.map(Date.constructor);
```

This code throws an Error on Google V8:

```js
SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

I'am also tried:

```js
a.map(Date.constructor, Date.prototype)
```

with the same result.

Comment: *That code should not result in a SyntaxError.* (Even though the operation is questionable otherwise: if `new` is not used during the invocation then the constructor function is ... just a normal function.) Is that all the code? Can you create a minimal jsfiddle test-case? Does it have a SyntaxError in FF/IE?

Comment: There is a mistake in my code. The Date.constructor is the Function object constructor. The Date object constructor is Date.prototype.constructor or just Date.

Comment: Found an answer. I will post it in a few hours.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The Date is a function, so the Date.constructor is a constructor of a function.
Proper call of the Date object constructor looks like this:

```js
Date.prototype.constructor();
```

Or just:

```js
Date();
```

The problem here is to create an array of Date objects with time values from array `a`,
but **it is impossible to call the Date object constructor and pass an arguments to it without a `new` operator (ECMA-262 15.9.2)**.

But it is possible for any object constructors that can be called as a functions with the same result as if i use the `new` operator (for instance the Error object constructor (ECMA-262 15.11.1)).

```js
$ var a = ['foo','bar','baz'];
$ a.map(Error);
> [ { stack: [Getter/Setter], arguments: undefined, type: undefined, message: 'foo' },
    { stack: [Getter/Setter], arguments: undefined, type: undefined, message: 'bar' },
    { stack: [Getter/Setter], arguments: undefined, type: undefined, message: 'baz' } ]
```

Comment: that’s wrong, those are just objects, not instances of Error. and if you map `.prototype.constructor` instead, suddenly `this` isn’t defined when calling functions added to the prototype.

Comment: @Antoniossss because the author accepted their own answer.

Comment: Right its authors answser.

Answer (score 8):

I think what the OP was looking for is strictly analogous to this:

```
var nums = [1, 2, 3];
var strs = nums.map(String);
//=> ['1', '2', '3']; // array of strings
```

I assume the reason is that this is really elegant, both in simple type-casting operations like above, and in more interesting tasks like converting one representation of something into a different representation, like so:

```
function MyCoolObject(oldObject) {
    // generates new object by consuming old one
    // maybe attach some cool class methods via prototype
    return this;
}

var newList = oldList.map(MyCoolObj);
//=> array of MyCoolObj based on oldObject
```

The problem with this appears to be that the new object, when created by passing the constructor to `Array.map`, is an extended version of the `window`; that is, `this` within the constructor refers to the global scope, which sucks because (1) it wasn't your goal to hang props on `window`, and (2) the objects you create this way are not unique instances.

For what it's worth, the original type-casting example isn't all it's cracked-up to be, either, because:

```
strs[0] instanceof String
//=> false // UGH!
```

The only solution I've come up with so far requires writing the constructor differently -- which you obviously can't do for native types like `Date`:

```
function Human(animal) {
    var h = new Object();
    h.species = 'human';
    h.name = animal.name;
    return h;
}

var humans = animals.map(Human);
```

By defining the return value as a new object, we sever the connection between the global scope and `this`; at least, that's what I assume is going on here. (You could also return a JSON literal instead of invoking `Object`.)

If I want these objects to have an interesting prototype, I have to define it separately and then attach it explicitly:

```
// this object will be used as the prototype for new Human instances
var HumanProto = {
    species: 'human',
    speak: function() { console.log('My name is ' + this.name); },
    canDrink: function() { return this.age >= 21; }
}

// then, in Human, make this change
var h = new Object(HumanProto);
```

In this case, it's not just as good to return JSON, because there don't appear to be any effective ways to set the prototype of an object-literal; and even if you could, you never want *this* to be true:

```
myObject.hasOwnProperty('prototype');
//=> true // only if myObject = { prototype: HumanProto }
```

I think the best way to ensure the new object has the desired prototype is to pass the would-be prototype as the argument to `new Object()`.

Is this pattern ideal? I don't know. It seems a little weird, since there are now two symbols associated with creating humans: `Human` the constructor function, and `HumanProto` the explicit prototype. More importantly, this seems like a real barrier if you've already got an ecosystem of fun custom classes that weren't written to be compatible with this pattern.

There is probably a better way out there. Maybe someone will post it.

Comment: Another problem with my solution is that you can't say `myHuman instanceof Human` -- you have to compare it to `HumanProto`, which is counter-intuitive and exposes the smoke-and-mirrors implementation. GROSS.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
a.map(function(obj) { return new Date(obj); });
```

Comment: Yes, but without anonymous function.

Comment: Why? It's a straightforward, working solution and doesn't create any significant overhead.

Comment: Because if I have an anonymous function which calls the constructor of object with its argument and returns a result, it is reasonable to call the constructor directly. In any case this is not possible in this case (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

The map method just iterates an array using the callback function provided (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/map). So:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4];
a.map(function(b) { return b+10; }); // [11, 12, 13, 14]
```

What are you trying to get from this:

```
Date.constructor(1);
Date.constructor(2);
Date.constructor(3);
```

**Update from comment:**

> The problem here is to create an array
>   of Date objects with time values from
>   array a by passing the Date object
>   constructor to a map function. Anyway
>   there is a mistake in the code(see
>   comment to pst) – set

I see, so something like:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4];
a.map(Date.prototype.constructor);
```

Comment: The problem here is to create an array of Date objects with time values from array `a` by passing the Date object constructor to a map function. Anyway there is a mistake in the code(see comment to pst)