# How to automatically apply argument to class constructor?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have an es6 class `User` and a global function `map()` given below:

```
class  User {
  constructor(public name: string) {}
}

const map = <T, R>(project: (value: T) => R) => {}
```

Instead of writing the following:

```
map((value) => new User(value))
```

I want to (somehow) write something like:

```
map(new User)
```

I am not sure if this is possible or not.

Comment: `new` calls the class. in the second one, you get the same instance for every call.

Comment: How can I otherwise pass the constructor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a constructor to Array.map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503010/passing-a-constructor-to-array-map)

Comment: @MateuszWitkowski not exact duplicate, because in that question Date object has static constructor function as I understand and in my case it is different. I want to understand how `new User` will work without passing argument

Comment: All that to save twelve characters?

Comment: Twelve multiplied by times of usage :D I want less boilerplate in code. Thanks for asking

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a static function in your class that takes the value param and returns a new User:

```
class User {
  static createUser(value) {
    return new User(value)
  }
}
```

And then use:

```
map(User.createUser)
```

Comment: To allow for subclassing, I'd recommend to do `return new this(value);` though - and then you'd have to `User.createUser.bind(User)`

Comment: Thanks, that looks great, but for now I am trying to understand how the class constructor is going to work

Comment: Good point to support subclassing. Binding context to functions is slow though. A good compromise would be to override the function in the subclass

Answer (score 5):

You can't do it directly. If you control the target function (ie it's not the stock `map` function) you can have it take a constructor instead of the function:

```
class User { constructor(private id: number) { }}
function map<TIn, T>(value: TIn, ctor: new (a: TIn) => T): T{
    return new ctor(value)
}
map(10, User)
```

Another more flexible solution is to use a helper function that transform the constructor into the desired function, although it's not much shorter then the original version:

```
class User { constructor(private id: number) { }}
function ctor<TIn, T>(ctor: new (a: TIn) => T): (value: TIn) => T{
    return value => new ctor(value)
}
[10, 11].map(ctor(User));
```

Comment: Yes I can actually control the map by writing my own high-order map function. I will try your version

Answer (score 2):

You could add a check with [`new.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target) if the function is called without new and call then function with [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).

```js
function Person(name) {
    if (!new.target) return new Person(...arguments);
    this.name = name;
}

var names = ['Jane', 'Dan', 'Grace', 'Paul'],
    instances = names.map(Person);

console.log(instances);
```

Comment: Could this work for es6 classes as well ? (If I convert `Person` to a class I get `Class constructor cannot be called without the new keyword` at runtime)

Comment: no, because you would need a static constructor, which does not work.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern you are describing is called a *scope-safe constructor*. It can be implemented by overloading a constructor so it works with *and* without the `new` keyword.

```
interface User {
  name: string;
}

interface UserConstructor {
  new (name: string): User;
  (name: string): User;
}
```

The same trick is used for global objects like `Array` or `Date`.

We need to recognize whether the `new` keyword was used:

```
const User = function (this: User | void, name: string): User {
  if (!(this instanceof User)) {
    return new User(name);
  }

  this.name = name;
  return this;
} as UserConstructor;
```

Your class has just become `new`-agnostic.

```
console.log(
  new User('Bob'),
  User('Alice'),
);
```

Which enabled us to write:

```
['Alice', 'Bob'].map(User); // $ExpectType User[]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a well known "problem" in the oop vs fp debate in JS - class constructors vs function constructors

since es6 classes **need** the `new` operator, it is impossible to write something like `map(new User)`

you need a wrapper around the class constructor that creates instances via a function call. IMO, [@baboo's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53956917/1343488) is way to go

```
class MyClass {
  // ...

  static create(...args) {
    return new MyClass(...args)
  }
}
const a = new MyClass('hello', [])
const b = MyClass.create('world', 123])
```

you can read more about the problems of `new` [here](http://www.ianbicking.org/blog/2013/04/new-considered-harmful.html).

also, checkout [daggy - Library for creating tagged constructors](https://github.com/fantasyland/daggy)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a generic solution, and can't modify the classes, you could use a higher-order function:

```
function make(klass) {
    return (...params) => new klass(...params);
}

// this:
map((value) => new User(value));

// becomes this:
map(make(User));
```