# What does 'void' as parameter in typescript mean?

Tags: typescript

I know what the type 'void' do on typescript.But i faced following code.

```
function (obj: void){}
```

I saw same on typescript documentation https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html

What does type  "void" as 
parameter of funсtion?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html

Answer (score 4):

`void` is useful as a `this` type, as it promises that you won't use the `this` parameter.

```
function f(this: void, ...) {
  // Can't use `this` in here.
}
```

On other parameters, it's... not as useful. If you have `--strictNullChecks` off, then you can still call the function by passing `null` or `undefined` as the void parameter. If you don't, then you can't even call the function, as `void` is uninhabited.

If you haven't seen `this` written as a function parameter before, I suggest you read [`this` section](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this) (pun entirely intended) of the documentation.

Comment: you can still call a `(a: void) => void` with no parameter or with `any`

Answer (score 0):

In short, `void` is used to denote *lack of value*. You can think of it as another way to say `undefined`.

```
const foo: void = undefined;
```

When used as the return type, `void` communicates that the function will not explicitly return anything.

```
function log(argument: any): void {
  console.log(argument);
}
```

Although in runtime `log` implicitly does return `undefined`, TypeScript makes the conceptual distinction between `void` and `undefined`.

```
function log(argument: any): void {
    console.log(argument);
}

const foo: undefined = log('Hello'); // Error — "void" is not "undefined"
```

When used as the `this` type, `void` communicates that the `this` used during a function call will be the default context of execution — the global scope. There are a few cases where it helps. Creating [scope-safe constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53956747/how-to-automatically-apply-argument-to-class-constructor/53980982#53980982) is one of them.